# Error trying to call a method on an object that belongs to another object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have recs, which belong to a list, and lists, which have many recs.  I am trying to figure out why I can't call my 'to_do' method below on the recs that belong to a list?  This is in the 2nd row of view code.  I'm getting the following error:

SQLite3::SQLException: near ")": syntax error: SELECT "recs".* FROM "recs"  WHERE "recs"."list_id" = ? AND (done = 'false'))

Rec Model

```
class Rec < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  scope :to_do, lambda {where("done = ?)", 'false')}
end
```

List model

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :recs
end
```

Controller

```
  def index
    @recs = Rec.to_do
    @lists = List.all
    @networks = Network.all
  end
```

View

```
  <% network.lists.eat_lists.each do |list| %>
    <% if list.recs.to_do.present? %>
      <%= list.name %></br>
      <% list.recs.each do |rec| %>
        <%= rec.name.split(',').first %>
        <%= rec.notes %>
        <%= rec.done %>
        <%= link_to 'Done', marked_as_done_url(rec), method: :patch %></br>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', rec, method: :delete %></br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your scope to this `scope :to_do, lambda {where("done = ?", false)}` or `scope :to_do, lambda {where(done:false}`, notice i have removed one closing bracket in string

Comment: A 2nd question on this same code.  I don't want to show a List if they have no Recs.  Is there a better way to do that, in the model or controller perhaps, that does this instead of writing if/then logic in the view itself?

Comment: Just remove `<% if list.recs.to_do.present? %>` and it will work fine.